# Is there a smarter way to bind layouts to fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have two XML layouts for one fragment. The code must choose between which of the two layouts it's going to Bind to. At the moment, this is my code.

*Here, I declare the two layout Bindings.*

```
private var bindingVariation: FragmentStartVariationBinding? = null
private var binding: FragmentStartBinding? = null
```

*In the onCreateView, the code checks which layout it's going to Bind to.*

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if(sharedViewModel.discountEnabled.value == true){
            val fragmentBinding = FragmentStartVariationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            bindingVariation = fragmentBinding
            bindingVariation?.startFragment = this
            bindingVariation?.viewModel = sharedViewModel
            return fragmentBinding.root
        }else{
            val fragmentBinding = FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            binding = fragmentBinding
            binding?.startFragment = this
            return fragmentBinding.root
        }
    }
```

This hack works for now, but if I want to call binding somewhere else in the class, I have to check every time if its binding or bindingVaration.

*This code naturally doesn't work but gives a good idea of what I want to achieve.*

```
private var binding = setBinding()

fun setBinding(){
   var exampleBinding? = null
   if(sharedViewModel.discountEnabled.value == true){
      return exampleBinding: FragmentStartVariationBinding? = null
   }else{
      return exampleBinding: FragmentStartBinding? = null
   }
}
```

Comment: my personal recommendation would be that you should just make two different fragments, each with their own appropriate layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes @a_local_nobody is right, you should have two fragments and decide which one to show based on your condition.

Answer (score 3):

The best scenario is that separate your fragment for each layout , but if you need to handle multi layout binding in one fragment , do like this :

**1 . declare your multi binding :**

```
    lateinit var bindingLarge : FragmentProfileLargeScreenBinding
    lateinit var binding : FragmentProfileBinding
```

**2 . assign them :**

```
    if (...) {
        bindingLarge = FragmentProfileLargeScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return R.layout.fragment_profile_large_screen
    }
    else {
        binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return R.layout.fragment_profile
    }
```

**3 . declare views like this :**

```
fun getTextWithdrawal() : Button {
    return if(this::binding.isInitialized)
        binding.textWithdrawal
    else
        bindingLarge.textWithdrawal
}
```

**4 . use views :**

```
getTextWithdrawal().setOnClickListener {...}
getTextWithdrawal().visibility = View.Visible
getTextWithdrawal(). ...
```